# How to display sum of entries from Array as output? [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I was trying to make a simple program that displays the total sales for all 12 months of the year and return the total amount of sales at the end of the user's input. I have looked at similar problems and tutorials that are related to mine; But it hasn't "clicked" in my head. Could I have some clarity on what is incorrect?

Thanks

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class monthArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of months for record: ");

    String dummy = scan.nextLine(); 

    String[] months = new String[] { "January", "Febuary", "March",
            "April", "May",
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
            "November", "December"};

    List list1 = Arrays.asList(months);



public long getTotal() 
    {

            long months = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
            {
                total += months[i];

            }

            return total;
        }


    System.out.println("\nEnter in the Total Sales for Each Month:");

    for(int i = 0; i < months.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Month " + (i + "; "));
        months[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("The list is:" + list1);

    System.out.println("\nThe numbers you entered are: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < months.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(months[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\nThe sum of all months are: ");

}
```

}

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, please let us know. Show the compilation error, like where you use months as a class variable when it has been declared locally in the main method. Also, you have a method nested within a method -- and that shouldn't work either.

Comment: Looking again at your code, you've got multiple errors, and this suggests that your style of coding perhaps needs to be fixed. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Instead if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code **early and often**, and most importantly **to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed**. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard to fix errors, like you're currently seeing.

Comment: You need to first declare the total variable like `long total = 0` and then return it after the for loop: `return total;`

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple foreach loop will get you the sum of all the elements:

```
int total = 0;
for (int value : months) {
  total += value;
}
```

What this does is create a new `total` variable, loop through every element in `value` (using a foreach loop) and increments the `total` variable by the value stored in the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define your method `getTotal()` in the body of `main`, it needs to be outside `main()` and you might use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Something like

```
public static float getTotal(float[] months) {
    float total = 0;
    for (float month : months) {
        total += month;
    }
    return total;
}
```

And then your `main()` can't define multiple arrays named `months`. I think you wanted something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of months for record: ");
    String[] months = new String[] { "January", "Febuary", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" };

    float[] monthlySales = new float[12];
    System.out.println("\nEnter in the Total Sales for Each Month:");
    for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Month %s [%d]; ", months[i], i);
        monthlySales[i] = scan.nextFloat();
    }
    System.out.println("The list is:" + Arrays.toString(monthlySales));
    System.out.printf("The sum of all months is %.2f%n",
            getTotal(monthlySales));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work for a variety of reasons and your question is not very clear, but I think there is an easy way to achieve what you seem to want. Let's start with defining the variable that will hold the total sales, an array containing the names of all months, and a Scanner which we will use to read data from the console:

```
double totalSales = 0;
String[] months = new String[]{"January", "February", "March", "April", 
        "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

After this, we can loop through the months and ask the user for the total sales in each one:

```
for(String month : months) {
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the total sales value for " + month + ": ");
    while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) { 
        sc.next();
    }
    totalSales += sc.nextDouble();
}
```

At the end of the loop we increment the total sales with the value informed by the user for each month. After the loop, the value stored in totalSales will be the total for the entire year.